# How do I create a a spiral that has a overlay that changes colors

Tags: python-turtle

I'm currently trying to make a program in which the turtle creates a spiral of circles, and once the spiral stops, the turtle will create a overlay of circles that should perfectly overlap the existing ones whilst constantly changing color, however the circles won't overlap, does anyone know on how to make the entire spiral change color or how to make the overlay of circles perfectly overlap? Here is my code so far.

````
painter = trtl.Turtle()
painter.speed(0)
painter.penup()
painter.color("salmon")
painter.pensize(2)

spiral_space = 0

while (spiral_space < 100): #here is where the spiral gets created
  painter.goto(0,0)
  painter.right(20)
  painter.forward(50+(spiral_space*1))
  painter.pendown()
  painter.circle(10)
  painter.penup()
  spiral_space = spiral_space + 1
  if (spiral_space % 1 == 0):
    painter.color("yellow")
  if (spiral_space % 2 == 0):
    painter.color("red")
    
line = 6 #and here is where the overlay starts to get created

while (line > 5): 
  painter.goto(0,0)
  painter.right(20)
  painter.forward(80)
  painter.pendown()
  painter.circle(10)
  painter.penup()
  line = line + 1 
  if (line % 18 == 0):
    painter.color("navy")
  if (line % 36 == 0):
    painter.color("salmon")

wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

> does anyone know on how to ... make the overlay of circles perfectly
> overlap

To answer your second question, the problem is that the original circles are drawn in a *spiral* but the overlay circles are drawn in a *circle*.  To make them overlap, you need to draw the overlay circles as one loop of the spiral:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

painter = Turtle()
painter.hideturtle()
painter.speed('fastest')
painter.color('salmon')
painter.pensize(2)
painter.penup()

spiral_space = 0

while spiral_space < 90:  # here is where the spiral gets created
    painter.goto(0, 0)
    painter.right(20)
    painter.forward(50 + spiral_space)
    painter.pendown()
    painter.circle(10)
    painter.penup()

    spiral_space += 1

    if spiral_space % 2 == 0:
        painter.color('red')
    else:
        painter.color('yellow')

line = 0
spiral_space = 0
painter.setheading(0)

while True:  # here is where the overlay gets created
    painter.goto(0, 0)
    painter.right(20)
    painter.forward(86 + spiral_space)
    painter.pendown()
    painter.circle(10)
    painter.penup()

    line += 1
    spiral_space += 1

    if line % 18 == 0:
        painter.color('navy')
        spiral_space = 0

    if line % 36 == 0:
        painter.color('salmon')
        spiral_space = 0

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

> does anyone know on how to make the entire spiral change color

To address your first question, I would restructure your program to make a spiral *of* turtles instead of a spiral *using* turtles:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

color_dictionary = {'red': 'navy', 'yellow': 'salmon', 'navy': 'red', 'salmon': 'yellow'}

def run():
    for clone in clones:
        clone.pencolor(color_dictionary[clone.pencolor()])

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(run, 1000)  # repeat in 1 second (1000 milliseconds)

screen = Screen()

previous = Turtle()
previous.hideturtle()
previous.shape('circle')
previous.shapesize(outline=2)
previous.fillcolor('white')
previous.penup()

clones = []

spiral_space = 0

while spiral_space < 90:
    clone = previous.clone()
    clone.hideturtle()
    clone.goto(0, 0)
    clone.right(20)
    clone.forward(50 + spiral_space)

    spiral_space += 1

    if spiral_space % 2 == 0:
        clone.pencolor('red')
    else:
        clone.pencolor('yellow')

    clone.showturtle()
    clones.append(clone)
    previous = clone

screen.tracer(False)

run()

screen.mainloop()
```

We can just loop through the turtles (`clones`) changing their color as we see fit.